# Returning null for string

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4, ios6

The below statement is returning null.

Could anyone please help?

NSString *movpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It mostly because the Movie.m4v not right in place, u need to add it to resource in build phase.